# How is Kotlin's Map.foreach better than the Java one?

Tags: java, kotlin, dictionary, lambda, foreach

A very simple example:

```
val map = mapOf("one" to 1, "two" to 2)
map.forEach{k, v -> if (k == "one") println(v)}  //Java API
map.forEach{(k, v) -> if (k == "two") println(v)}  //Kotlin extension
```

I am confused by the IDE warning `Java Map.forEach method call should be replaced with Kotlin's forEach` for the second line. I don't understand why should I replace it. They seem to work identically, and the only difference is the java method requiring 2 less symbols to type. Any ideas?

Comment: When I try this, both of those ways end up using the kotlin extension. To get it to use the java `.forEach` I had to write it this way `map.forEach({k, v -> if(k=="one") println(v)})` (The difference being that the whole lambda is inside the parens, while kotlin wants the lambda immediately preceeding the function name.)

Comment: @EricGeorge Hm, what version of kotlin did you use? Mine is 1.6.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If nothing else, it's an inline function, and can more efficiently do things like mutate state elsewhere or smoothly incorporate suspend functions.

Using the same `forEach` everywhere is simpler than having to track which one you're using at any given point.

Comment: So, kotlin's lambdas get inlined while java's cannot?

Comment: Right, Java functions are never inlined. There will be an allocation for the functional interface.

Comment: I mean, not _strictly_ necessarily -- e.g. the specified lambda could be allocated as a singleton, so it's only allocated once and never again.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers: the Java method is only available in Kotlin/JVM, while **the Kotlin function is cross-platform** and can also be used in Kotlin/Native and Kotlin/JS. So without good reasons to use the Java version, it makes sense to default to the Kotlin version with its greater compatibility.